# Knockout if binding

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

```
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: observable1">
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: A"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: B"></td>

        </tr>
        <tr data-bind="foreach: observable2">
            <!-- ko if:C() == A() --> 
            <td data-bind="text: C"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: D"></td>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tr>
       </tbody>
```

According to the html seen above, I am using knockout if binding to display the second row. The second row should be displayed only when value of column C matches with the value of Column A.
I am unable to use column A from observable1 as knockout throws error. Is this possible to do ?

Comment: Ah, I'll add it as an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the parent context within a binding expression using `$parent`:

```
<!-- ko if:C() == $parent.A() -->
```

You can also refer to the root of your model using `$root`.  See the documentation on [Binding Context](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) for more information.

Hope this helps!